# how do i put my condition result into a list?

Tags: python, string, list, numbers

I want to open a file, get numbers after the `=` sign, and put the result into a list.  I did the first steps, but I'm stuck with assignment of the results into a list.

I tried to create a list and assign the result on it but when I print my list it shows me only the last results:

```
import cv2 as cv
import time
import numpy
from math import log
import csv
import re

statList = []

with open("C:\\ProgramData\\OutilTestObjets3D\\MaquetteCB-2019\\DataSet\\DEFAULT\\terrain\\3DObjects\\building\\house01.ive.stat.txt", 'r') as f:
    #
    statList = f.readlines()
    statList = [x.strip() for x in statList]
    for line in statList :
        if (re.search("=" ,str(line))):
            if (re.search('#IND',str(line))):
                print("ERREUR")
            else:
                results = re.findall("=\s*?(\d+\.\d+|\d+)", str(line))
                print ("result="+str(results))
                statList.append(log(float(results[0])))

                floatList = [str(results)]
                print(floatList)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are overwriting results variable each time through your loop. 
try

```
    #
results = []
statList = f.readlines()
statList = [x.strip() for x in statList]
for line in statList :
    if (re.search("=" ,str(line))):
        if (re.search('#IND',str(line))):
            print("ERREUR")
        else:
            results.extend(re.findall("=\s*?(\d+\.\d+|\d+)", str(line)))
            print ("result="+str(results))
            statList.append(log(float(results[0])))

            floatList = [str(results)]
            print(floatList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your program is defining an empty list `statList`, then redefine it as `statList = f.readlines()` and append `results` to it. So, change the name of empty list, then you can use `extend` as long as `results` are list objects. And finally, use built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function to apply a function for every single item of your list:

```
from math import log
import re

final_result = []
with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    #
    statList = f.readlines()
    statList = [x.strip() for x in statList]
    for line in statList :
        if (re.search("=" ,str(line))):
            if (re.search('#IND',str(line))):
                print("ERREUR")
            else:
                result = re.findall("=\s*?(\d+\.\d+|\d+)", str(line))
                print("result=" + result[0])
                final_result.extend(result)
                #  final_result.append(result[0])

floats_list = list(map(float, final_result))
logs_list = list(map(log, floats_list))
```

Comment: thats kinda worked but i dont  a list tho , the result is something like that:21.9503
14.4585
762.834
6696.64
91.486
59.5954
60.0636

but i want those result into square brackets like [21.9503
14.4585
762.834
6696.64
91.486
59.5954
60.0636
......]

Comment: nevermind i'm just dumb thats worked perfectly, really thank you !

Comment: @skehal if you wanna check the type of your data, please use `print(type(floats_list))`, which results `<class 'list'>`. It shows the data are in bracket indeed. I used `map` function to show you a python's instrument.